# IOS6 Safari Ajax Spinner

Tags: ios, ajax, mobile-safari, cors, safari

I can make a CORS Ajax post work fine on IOS6, but there are some very weird behaviours in regards to the little spinner that indicates that the browser is loading something despite the  request completing.

I have provided a live page that demonstrates this behaviour [here](http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ios6.spinner/ios6.html)

And the source for the node.js + express server is available [here](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ios6.spinner/ios6.zip)

Note this only occurs on IOS6, in addition it behaves inconsistently between tabs, for example you can navigate to another page on same tab and it will continue to spin, but open a second tab, load the page, then close the first tab and it goes away.

Also if you run the test page, then go to a different site using the same browser tab, the spinner will continue to spin on the new site.

So what I'm looking for is some hack that might make this behave in a sensible way, I'm not interested in not using Ajax, CORS or POST.

Thanks for taking the time and having a look.

Update: Apple have confirmed the issue but nothing more, so will just wait and see if next release fixes it.  I am going to stop the test server but leave the files available.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this issue independently today too. I reduced my test case and found that this only happens on CORS request that trigger preflight requests. So it leads me to believe that it's related to two requests firing off in succession. OPTIONS and then whatever method your request is.

It also doesn't matter at what stage you firing off the request as soon as a preflight CORS request is triggered the spinner never goes away.

UPDATE: Just tried the iOS7 beta and this bug is still present.

Comment: Useful analysis, I have been told this will be fixed in IOS7

Comment: Just wondering if you have filed an issue with Apple? If so are you able to add the details to http://openradar.appspot.com/ so we can publicly track this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    getUpdates();
});

function getUpdates() {
    $.post("status.jsp", {}, function(status){

        // do client-side rendering here

        setTimeout(getUpdates, 5000);
    }, "json");
}
```

Go to this site for more info.
http://www.devthought.com/2012/09/22/understanding-the-ios6-ajax-bugs/

Comment: My issue was closed by Apple and marked as duplicate, but they don't allow you to see the issue that it is a duplicate of!